# Verisign certification for subdomain through IP

Tags: iis, ssl, https, certificate, verisign

I have purchaseed SSL secure Site from Verisign. 
So I have configured it and its working fine on https://www.myExample.com which ip is 123.123.123.123.

As ssl bein configurated to the domain name 'myExample.com' when I acces to the server url through IP like https://123.123.123.123 I see that warning 'this site is not secure..'

Having the ssl to the domain, there is a way to change (or adapt) it also for the server ip (who is exactly the same)? Or I have to buy a new license only for the ip as a web hostname?

Thanks!

David

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure that certificates will work with IP, but in that case, yes, you should have 2 certicates, 1 for the domain name access, and 1 for ip access.

Answer (score 1):

Verisign does not know nor care about your IP address assignment.
Your certificate contains DNS name for your domain name, like `www.myexample.com`.
If you don't want your browser to complain about signature being invalid, you must confgure DNS properly.

If you don't want to configure DNS right now, you can temporarily add custom named IP record to `/etc/hosts` or `%WINDOWS%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`. But, this will only affect one computer where this change was made, and is not really recommended - just fix DNS already!

Comment: its not really our dns problem, it's a costumer's proxy configuration problem.. so we can't do anything about that